# Flex : Hide a menu item from Menu?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

- How to hide menu item from Menu object ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. Though there is a "enabled" property detected on the items you give to menubar, there is no such thing as "visible" property. I've searched for it ! :-) I've ended by manually looping over my menu items and removing them or adding theme from a raw, untouched collection of menuitems, so that the menubar only gets what it is supposed to display.

Comment: it is still sufficient answer :) Thank you very much .. i am goin into "looping raw's" aswell then :)